# How to change the default-search-path values for GNU GCC for regular usage?

Tags: gcc, environment-variables, gnu

GNU GCC Compiler Environment Variables **Default-Search-Path** — I am trying to change default values of GCC environment variables to new custom values so that the default search path will contain any needed additional libraries or include header files that I would like to use on a regular basis.

My version of GNU GCC is: ***gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0***

Include directories for .h header files for this `<…>` not `"…"` which would be in the same directory as .c file extension.

#### Include Header Directories:

1. CPATH
2. C_INCLUDE_PATH
3. CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
4. OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH

#### Library File Directories:

1. LIBRARY_PATH

I realized that these are Windows Environment Variables.
And That I could Simply just create Windows User Environment Variables.

Here is a command which will show default search paths for GNU GCC Compiler.

```
cpp -v
```

This shows include directory default search path.

```
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

This shows library directory default search path.

This Command Prompt Command tells me the default-search-paths which are set during installation of GNU GCC Compiler I assume these are considered Environment Variables and I am looking to see if anyone on the web could give me any urls in regards to changing this default search path value.

Here are a few links related to what I am doing. I used that information although I was still unable to accomplish what I was intending to accomplish.

- [GCC environment variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)
- [C Preprocessor search path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path)
- [C preprocessor environment variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables)
- [GCC configuration](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear what your question is, or if your question is actually a question, or a combination of a question and an answer? Please edit to clarify. Note: If you are indeed trying to answer your own question, then place the answer in a proper *answer*, not as part of the question.

Comment: Please edit your question to add any specifics (you shouldn't be posting all this additional detail in comments). The question itself is unclear as written, and it's very hard to figure out what you're asking with additional information spread across several comments. You've mentioned some additional details in follow-on comments, and they should all be edited into the original question.

Comment: @CharlesVictorWright: **why do you ask?** What you want to do seems a very bad idea !

Answer (score 1):

### Recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers have some (optional) [`.spec` file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html)s.

You could edit yours, and that file drives the actual compilation processes. As you know, `gcc` is mostly starting some `cc1` / `cc1plus` internal program (then `ld`)

### But I recommend to *not* edit your `.spec` file.

Instead of that, **configure your build procedure**, e.g. edit your `Makefile` for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or your `build.ninja` file (actually, the generator of that file) for [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) builder.

#### Of course, read the chapter about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

BTW, GNU make has a lot of built-in rules. Use `make -p` to understand them.

You could also take inspiration from [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

You could also code your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), implementing your own `#pragma` which would customize the behavior of `gcc`. I am not sure it is a good idea.

> How to change the default-search-path values?

### don't do that, learn to use GCC instead

You might want, from time to time, to compile your code with [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), to check that your code base is not tied to one particular compiler.

You could use [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your C code. In some cases, some bugs could be found at compile time. You certainly want to [pass *explicitly*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) both `-Wall` and `-Wextra` to `gcc` (and notice that `clang` accepts them also)

PS. This is from a [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) perspective. Adapt that to your proprietary operating system. Or consider getting the permission to switch to Linux (see also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report funded by the [CHARIOT](https://chariotproject.eu/) European project).

Comment: Is it possible to add images to this Question Just one image which I added to the edit of the question?

Comment: Your explanation sounds extremely Complicated although It looks like I would attempt to do that technique when I get more experience with the GNU GCC Compiler! Thanks For the Help! Truly Appreciate It! QUICK RESPONSE!

Comment: No, my explanation is simple: **don't change the default-search-path-values** but read the documentation of GCC and **learn to use GCC correctly**, according to established habits.